# Where I can find RemotingServices.CreateTransparentProxy implementation?

Tags: c#, wcf, clr, transparentproxy

I'm trying to get insights about how transparent proxy created by WCF ChannelFactory work by digging into source codes. [CreateTransparentProxy](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/remotingservices.cs,61aac7041ef84f3d) is marked by `extern` keyword and `[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]` attribute which means that I must look implementation inside CLR as long as my understanding goes. In [CLR source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) I found only one mention of function that I need in some sort of c# to c++ code functions mapping file [ecalllist.h](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/e04cf873bda6d44e096a38921e54c9d12eac0c6a/src/vm/ecalllist.h). So implementation must be lying within class called `RemotingNative`, but search within repository doesn't give me any result on that. 
I've found some old SSCLI codes on github which contains [similar method implementation](https://github.com/lewischeng-ms/sscli/blob/adbd6bbad0816f65650a66e1701112a307dc4b09/clr/src/vm/remoting.cpp) but not exactly the same. And besides that I want to look at actual implementation.

Comment: Note that "sscli" is the "Shared Source CLI" implementation from Microsoft, and by no means decompiled. It has been developed by Microsoft during the .NET 1.x/2.0 timeframe to show that the CLR can actually be cross platform and to support ECMA specification. It is based on the .NET 2.x source code so it might still be pretty accurate with respect on your issue. If you want the "original" SSCLI source code, look [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4917).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WCF become [open sourced](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/) the other day. What I found so far is that WCF `ServiceChannelProxy` now use `DispatchProxy.Create<T, TProxy>()` instead of `RemotingServices.CreateTransparentProxy()`.
 So it looks like if you want *actual* implementation of method that creates *proxy used by WCF*, than [DispatchProxy](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy/src/System/Reflection/DispatchProxy.cs) and [DispatchProxyGenerator](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy/src/System/Reflection/DispatchProxyGenerator.cs) are places that you look for. If you want *actual* implementation of `RemotingServices.CreateTransparentProxy()` than SSCLI codes may be a good approximation as @Christian.K pointed out.